# Knapsack problem with multiple constraints

Tags: algorithms, knapsack-problems

I am unsure if I have even identified the problem correctly, but reading up on [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) seems the closest to what I am trying to solve:

> A cook has $k$ ingredients of $p$ quantities. Given a
>   list of $n$ unique recipes, each consisting varying ingredients of varying
>   quantities. 
>   Now, the cook would like to use all ingredients on ONE recipe with minimal leftovers.

What is his solution? And can it be determined in $O(\log n)$ time?

`Sample input`

500 pounds of flour
300 mg sugar
5 mg of vanilla pods
20 eggs

`Database of possible recipes`:

Thai Fried Noodles (doesn't contain vanilla or flour, but contains 1 tablespoon of sugar)

Tiramisu (doesn't contain flour and vanilla but contains 3 tablespoons of sugar and 8 eggs)

Anna's Special Tiramiu (doesn't contain flour and vanilla but contains 1 tablespoons of sugar and 8 eggs)

Truffle Tagliatelle (doesn't contain any input ingredients)

**EDIT** Cost/benefit decision:

Given the sample input, `Tiramisu` recipe is the most preferred because among the 4 recipes in the database, it contains the most number of input ingredient type (2 of 4 types), and the most number of input ingredient quantity.

Expected result where 1) is the top search result of relevance:
1) Tiramisu
2) Anna's Special Tiramisu
3) Thai Fried Noodles
4) Truffle Tagliatelle

**EDIT:** I believe my question is a variant of the [integer knapsack problem](http://www.g12.cs.mu.oz.au/wiki/doku.php?id=simple_knapsack)

Comment: First of all, I don't think the question is well defined. What do you mean by "to minimize waste"? Does not being able to use 1 egg out of 8 as bad as not being able to use 1ml of milk? More formally, there is no well-defined cost/penalty function of not using various ingredients.  Secondly, what is $n$? Is it the number of ingredients or the number of recipies?

Comment: After the edit, I assume the quantities of varying ingredients are comparable. I also assume, that there are $m$ ingredients available to the cook. Under these assumptions, *just checking* if a given recipe can be made using the ingredients will take $O(m)$ time. To find all recipes which are feasible will take $O(mn)$ time. If you assume all recipes are feasible, you still need to check each and every one in $O(mn)$ time, unless they are structured in some special order.

Comment: hey guys, someone misunderstood my question and edited the original. im fixing it now

Comment: If it's Knapsack it's unlikely to be solvable in polynomial time (by an easy algorithm).

Comment: Why do I feel it's much easier than it pretends to be and is actually linear in the size of the input? Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: @bouncingHippo, my apologies for editing incorrectly. Are the recipes ordered in any way? $O(\log n)$ time sounds like binary search to me.

Comment: @Merbs no worries...at the moment the recipes are not ordered in any way. The goal of `O(log n)` is due to its speed and high performance

Comment: @bouncingHippo To formulate an algorithm, the problem needs to be defined precisely. So for your sample input, how does 500 pounds of flour compare with 300 mg sugar or to 20 eggs. Suppose one recipe A requires everything except 200 pounds of flour, while another recipe B requires everything except 300 mg sugar. Which recipe should be preferred? Should A be preferable just because the number 200 is greater than 300? Or should they be in the same units (in which case, what about 20 eggs)?

Comment: @Paresh, thanks for clarifying me for the cost/benefit decision. Given the sample input, `Tiramisu` recipe is the most preferred because among the 4 recipes in the database, it contains the most number of input ingredient type, and the most number of input ingredient quantity

Comment: Assuming you're searching for the optimal recipe many times with different ingredients/quantities, it might be possible to organize them in such a way to accomplish $O(\log n)$; that is, [amortized analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) for **one** recipe. Two recipes is another ball game.

Comment: @Merbs it's more like given a fixed basket of ingredients i have at home, which recipe can i use in a database of recipes that can preferably use up all of the ingredients i have at home

Comment: How would you answer Paresh's comment? That checking them in less than $O(mn)$ is impossible without some structure? Otherwise my answer is that you should (a) organize the recipes to allow for quicker searches or (b) search through all of the recipes.

Comment: @Merbs assume that all units are automatically converted from imperial to metric. Per Paresh comparison of 200mg vs 300mg of sugar between Recipe A and Recipe B. If I understand it correctly, both recipes use up ALL of the cook's ingredients except for needing extra 200mg sugar. In that case, Recipe A is preferred because it requires **lesser quantity** of additional ingredients

Comment: @Merbs i think the naive solution is `O(mn)` based on Paresh's 2nd comment and i am looking for anything that's faster than that, preferably at `O (log n)`

Comment: @Paresh you mention that it is possible to make it faster by structuring the recipes in a special order. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: @bouncingHippo I think you may have misread my comment slightly. The comparison was between 200 *pounds* of flour vs 300 mg of sugar. Similarly, what is more important to you: more number of ingredients are used or total wastage is less? For example, suppose you have 5 units each of 3 ingredients. Recipe C needs 1 unit of each of the 3 ingredients (12 units of ingredients wasted, but 3 out of 3 ingredients used). Recipe D needs 5 units each of 2 ingredients (only 5 units of ingredients wasted but only 2 ingredients used). Which is better?

Comment: Note that these are not two constraints, as your title seems to suggest, but different parameters to be optimized. They need to be defined more precisely. In any case, I will attempt an answer under the assumption that you will be able to precisely compare any two given recipes.

Comment: @Paresh at first glance, i would think (1) more ingredients are used and (2) total wastage is less are the same. however, i think what's more important is that (1) more ingredients used is more important in this case. So, Recipe D would be preferred in this case

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can compare two recipes and say which would be preferable to the other. That is, you can define an order between them. Then:

1. You need to find appropriate recipe only **once** (or very few times). A simple scan through all the recipes is the only way possible. You *need* to look at *every* recipe at least *once* to be able to see if it is good enough or not. This will give linear complexity.
2. You have to find appropriate recipes **repeatedly for a lot of different baskets**. Then, it would make sense to order the recipes in a way that searching would be faster. You might want to sort the recipes first once, in $O(n\log n)$ time. Then, whenever you encounter a basket of ingredients for which you want to find the best recipe, you search the sorted list of ingredients using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) in $O(\log n)$ time. Thus, the pre-processing phase (sorting) will be slow, but subsequent queries will be fast. This will be beneficial only when you have millions of recipes and want to search the best matched recipe for different baskets hundreds or thousands of times each second.

Admittedly, this is a little vague, but based on the given information, this is the best I can give.